# How does rebase work when you pull first (always on master branch)?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-rebase, git-pull

I have a remote repository and 2 clones.
In one of the clones I do 2 commits and push them.
In the other repository I do one commit and do: `git pull & --rebase`
I expect that in the end the `master` will point to my commit preceded by the 2 commits that I pulled.
But what I see is the following:

```
*   2b90a9c (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'master' of   https://user@repos/myrepos.git  
|\
| * 2d29cff (origin/master) Added call to reverse sort in main  
| * 5686863 Added call to sort in main  
* | 819ae7e Some stupid comment  
* |   bc5e9d9 Added a count?  
|\ \
| |/
```

commit `819ae7e Some stupid comment` was my last commit before doing pull and rebase. It seems that it applied what I pulled on top of my last commit of my local master.
Why? Isn't rebase saving in tmp files what you are on, applying the ones you are rebasing and then apply what you saved? Why it did this in reverse way?

When I run `git status` I get:
`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits`

What 4 commits? I only see it to be one commit ahead. (`2d29cff` vs `2b90a9c`)

Comment: What does "`git pull & --rebase`" mean? Did you just mean "`git pull --rebase`"?

Comment: I do a `git pull` followed by a `rebase`.

Comment: Oh... so "`git pull && git rebase`"?

Comment: @Johnsyweb:Now that you mention this, I did a typo when I run the command. I run just now `git pull && git rebase` and the log tree is as expected.So what is the log tree I got previously?

Comment: It looks like the `rebase` part didn't happen because of the typo.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:So what did the `git pull` do?

Comment: It `fetch`ed `origin/master` and `merge`d it into `master`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:And the second `rebase`?

Answer (score 0):

```
git pull --rebase
```

is what you're talking about. Rebasing can be made the default for `git pull` in the config too for less typing. What the rebase option on pull does is it takes any commits you have not pushed yet, gets new ones since the last common point, then puts your local commits not yet push on top of those.